# Some UI elements don't acquire UIAppearance traits

Tags: ios, ios5, uiview, uilabel

I am trying to use `UIAppearance` to get a uniform color theme in my iOS app. For example I try to set the text color of all `UILabel` objects as follows:

```
[[UILabel appearance] setTextColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0.7 green:0.07 blue:0.12 alpha:1]];
```

This works fine for all objects statically defined in my storyboard/XIBs. However, sometimes I need to dynamically create a UILabel in a view. In these cases, the UIAppearance is not used. Instead the default text color (black) is used instead.

Has anyone run into this issue/ found a way around it other than resorting to the old "set every element manually" approach?

Comment: That's really odd.  I notice that if I create the dynamic labels and **then** set their appearance it works...but I don't imagine that helps for most cases.

Comment: I actually tried that, but it didn't work for me either. So far, I just create the label and then call `myLabel.textColor = [[UILabel appearance] textColor]` to set it to whatever the current color UIAppearance color is, but it seems like that misses the point of UIAppearance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems that not all the classes support UIAppearance and UILabel is not one of those.

Check this question for more info: 
[UIAppearance not taking effect on UILabels created programatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11308379/uiapperance-not-taking-effect-on-uilabels-created-programatically)

Here's a list of classes that support UIAppearance:
http://blog.mosheberman.com/list-of-classes-that-support-uiappearance-in-ios-5/

Comment: yet somehow UILabel.appearance compiles. Thanks Apple