# UILabel Appearance in Monotouch

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, uilabel, uiappearance

Why the appearance settings are not working on my controls in monotouch 6?
I'm setting a properties

```
UILabel.Appearance.Font = UIFont.FromName("Fontname", 16);
UILabel.Appearance.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Clear;
```

But when i'm creating a label

```
UILabel mLabel = new UILabel(new RectangleF(0, 0, width, height));
```

It looks like default label. With white background and dark text.
And if i set a properties directly it works fine

```
mLabel.Font = UIFont.FromName("Fontname", 16);
mLabel.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Clear;
```

Gives me a correct result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like this problem [is not specific to MonoTouch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11817191/458193).
Quoting Joshua from [another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11839198/458193),

> OK, it turns out that you cannot style any `UILabel` properties using the `UIAppearance` proxy.
>
> While the `UILabel` class conforms to the `UIAppearanceContainer` protocol, a check of UILabel.h shows that none of its properties are marked with `UI_APPEARANCE_SELECTOR`, the prerequisite for the use of `UIAppearance`.

Which is annoying.

Comment: Thanks for the clarifications! Finally i came to my own proxy class for creating ui controls.